# How do I set and use tabs in PDFsharp?

Tags: tabs, pdfsharp, tabstop

I'm trying to figure out how to use tabs in **PDFsharp**.  I have a simple document with tabs set at 1", 2", 3" and 4".  Each tab space is 1" wide.  Each are left justified.
How do I set the tabs and how do I print to each tab.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Use MigraDoc if you want to use tabs (left, center, right, decimal).

With PDFsharp, you draw text wherever you want to have it. It is up to you to implement the tab scheme yourself.